# Can someone help me please, regarding the rules on pseudo classes, and how to place them please?

Tags: css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I can't seem to find the correct class in CSS, to add at the end o the paragraph 2 and 3 the word "NEW" in yellow, whenevere I get close the second div manages to inherit the command as well.
And also when I try to make just the last paragraph italic, when hover, the second div inherits it as well, and so it makes the 8th paragraph as well italic when hover.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juWDn.png)

Comment: I'm new to this, still in class, and this is the advanced CSS, also, I cannot make any changes to the HTML file, only in CSS

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67925908/edit) your question to include code as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

If I add the display: none; property to the seconde div and the class in question mentioning the second div as well, it solves my problem